# auto-pst-pdf problem - no cropped <file>-autopp.pdf

Tags: auto-pst-pdf

I'm trying to get some PSTricks pictures to PDF. I'm using the information provided on http://tug.org/PSTricks/main.cgi?file=pdf/pdfoutput#autopstpdf

Well, never change a running system ... yesterday it worked, but due to HDD problems I had to reinstall my system (Win XP sp3, Miktex 2.9, Texniccenter 2.02). The thing is, the final .pdf is created, Latex->PDF, XeLatex->PFD, ... it doesn't matter. But what I would need is the cropped .pdf from the picture itself, the <'file'-autopp.pdf>.

Perl (5v18) ist installed (although before the reinstallation I didn't have it). I got the "typical" two warnings, which I found quite often in forums, but those guys just needed the final .pdf, I would need the cropped pictures.

Using:

```
 \documentclass[12pt]{article}

 \usepackage[pdf]{pstricks}
 \usepackage[crop=off]{auto-pst-pdf}
 \usepackage{pst-pdf}

 \begin{document}
 \input{a.pstricks}
 \end{document}
```

Getting (umformen.log):         (... .tex-file is called "umformen")

```
[...]
    runsystem(echo "-------------------------------------------------")...executed.
    runsystem(echo "auto-pst-pdf: Auxiliary LaTeX compilation")...executed.
    runsystem(echo "-------------------------------------------------")...executed.
    runsystem(del "umformen-autopp.log")...executed.

    runsystem(latex -disable-write18 -jobname="umformen-autopp" -interaction=batchmode  "\let \APPmakepictures \empty \input
      umformen.tex")...executed.

    Package auto-pst-pdf Warning: 
        Creation of umformen-autopp.dvi failed.
    This warning occured on input line 124.

    Package auto-pst-pdf Warning: 
        Could not create umformen-pics.pdf. Auxiliary files not deleted.
    This warning occured on input line 124.
    runsystem(echo "-------------------------------------------------")...executed.
    runsystem(echo "auto-pst-pdf: End auxiliary LaTeX compilation")...executed.
    runsystem(echo "-------------------------------------------------")...executed.
[...]
```

Because the whole system is reinstalled, I think the error is maybe somewhere else? Anyone any clues?

Greetings, Florian

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: There can be clues in `umformen-autopp.log` if it exists. Otherwise the DVI generation can be done manually using the quoted command line `latex -disable-write18 -jobname=umformen-autopp ... umformen.tex"`.

Comment: Using the command line I get a .dvi, but I'm not quite sure, what do do with that?  
The umformen-autopp.log does exist.  
>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`\begin{pspicture}` instead of `\begin{picture}`

I was using the programm "JPicEdt" to actually draw the picture. One can choose the type of picture: "Emulated Latex", "PSTricks", ... Unfortunatly the type was wrong configurated, also in the minimal I made (a.pstricks), which infact wasn't minimal, but one step over minimal, including the error.
Changing the type does change the output file (pspicture -> picture), although the "save"-button stays gray. Maybe somehow the error got in there.

Hoping to help somebody, thanks for helping me!
Florian

Answer (score 2):

that cannot work, because a package is not loaded twice. `\usepackage[pdf]{pstricks}` already loads `auto-pst-pdf`. Try

```
 \documentclass[12pt]{article}

 \usepackage{ifpdf}
 \usepackage[crop=off]{auto-pst-pdf}
 \ifpdf\else\usepackage{pstricks}\fi

 \begin{document}
 \input{a.pstricks}
 \end{document}
```

and also:

```
 \documentclass[12pt]{article}

 \usepackage{ifpdf}
 \usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}
 \ifpdf\else\usepackage{pstricks}\fi

 \begin{document}
 \input{a.pstricks}
 \end{document}
```

I tried the *first* example and an up-to-date MiKTeX 2.9 on a Windows 7.0 with a file `a.pstricks`:

```
\begin{pspicture}
\psframe*[linecolor=blue](10,10)
\end{pspicture}
```

and had no problems (running TeXmaker with enabled `--shell-escape`)

Comment: I tried both, both not working, same two warnings and no ..-autopp.pdf

Comment: ok, then use the example with `\usepackage[cleanup={}]{auto-pst-pdf}`. What files were created?

Comment: Using this line I get a u*.aux, u*.log, u*.pdf, u*.synctex, u*-autopp.log - and of course the two warnings occure

Comment: it looks like that you have no write access for that directory where the external file is written.

Comment: Using XP, specially just as one user, I didn't think the problem was there. Today I tried from the beginning, and it worked. So I tried to find the error. I'm not completely sure, but I think it's a \begin{picture} instead of \begin{pspicture}, which causes all the troubles.

Comment: FYI: The first code-lines Herbert gave me are working as well as my own. The second lines return 4 warnings and the output is just a -autopp.pdf, but uncropped. Thanks, Florian

Comment: yes `\begin{picture}` is valid LaTeX code, but won't work with `auto-pst-pdf`

Comment: +1 I will remove this comment shortly: Why did you make `texdoc pst-perspective` launch German version rather than English version?